# Forward-looking dock/hub for 2012 Macbook Pro Retina

Tags: dock, thunderbolt

My main machine is a 2012 Macbook Pro Retina, AKA MacBookPro10,1. Its fastest ports are good ol' fashioned Thunderbolt 1. I would like a dock for it.

I would use such a setup with a keyboard, monitor, and USB devices.

I could buy a traditional Thunderbolt dock, but I would prefer to buy something future-proof. And Thunderbolt 3/USB-C docks are cheaper than traditional Thunderbolt docks now that the connector is getting common. Apple offers a USB-C/Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 1/2 adapter: http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter
Everything I have read indicates that a Thunderbolt 3 dock would work with an adapted Thunderbolt 1 port.  (I understand that such a setup wouldn't work as a power supply with my present laptop).

Does anyone a Thunderbolt 3 docking station with a Thunderbolt 1 adapter in practice? Does it work as it ought to in theory?

Comment: How did you go with this? Looking at that product it looks like it goes the wrong way - the male end should go into the computer, but it's the USB-C end, no? I have the same situation...

Comment: Didn't end up buying anything and the computer just died, so I guess I'll buy some kind of USB-C/Thunderbolt dock now.